# How to add an icon to the WooCommerce “Proceed to Checkout” & "Update Cart" buttons located on the cart page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a "[fa-chevron-circle-right](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-circle-right/)" icon to the "Proceed to Checkout" button and add another icon to the "Update Cart" button.

I've tried changing this

```
<input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout &rarr;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
```

to this

```
<button type="submit" class="checkout-button button btn-primary alt" name="proceed"><?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
```

but for some reason the button no longer works. When you click the "Proceed to Checkout" using the button `<button>` tag it does not proceed to the checkout page like it does when using the default `<input>` button.

Using CSS3 `:after` or `:before` doesn't work on `<input>` tags either.

I've also tried adding a jQuery form submit trigger to my custom buttons which is not work.  At this point the only hacked solution that I can think of is to visually hide the `<input>` buttons and trigger their submission via jQuery.

Comment: I've actually installed Wp & Woo to test this, and despite changing it to: `<button>` and included the icon, I could still successfully proceed to checkout with any errors - what WP and Woo Commerece versions do you have?

Comment: @MackieeE The issue is occurring on WP3.8 and WooCommerce 2.0.20.

Comment: I have a some problem today & I just add `value="1"` to the button. If the value is empty [update] & [proceed to checkout] doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same type of issue a while ago and here it's what I did to solve the problem.

Add a class submit to your button

```
<button type="submit" class="checkout-button button btn-primary alt submit" name="proceed"><?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
```

And on the JavaScript file this part to submit (better to be include on the footer of the page before the `</body>`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".submit").click(function(){ $(this).closest("form").submit(); });
</script>
```

Comment: "type" is meaningless on a button. I think you meant to say `class="submit"`

Comment: @EliasRodrigues sorry, oddly that is not working. I've tried a similar solution to that as well it but it working either. I've tried increasing the quantity of a product and then running `$('form.cart-form').submit();` form the browser console but the page reloads back to the prior quantity. :(

Comment: @randak What do you mean by 'type' being meaningless for a button? `type=submit` is listed in in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) as an attribute of the HTML5 button tag.

Comment: @Micah did you check with a tool like firebug(or similar tool) to see if nothing else it's interfering with the code?

Comment: @EliasRodrigues I've done all I know how to do with Chrome Developer Tools to troubleshoot the issue. Is there something in particular you have in mind that I could try with firebug or a similar tool?

Comment: You can safely ignore what I said, I guess I just don't see the point of putting the type AND having a script that submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to add background image instead of editing its core file like you can see below

```
.woocommerce button.checkout-button {
 background-image: images/pathtoimages.png;

}
```

Comment: Our preference and practice is to use CSS for styling instead of images.